# solr - Is it possible to set column weights in the schema (rather than in the query)

Tags: search, solr

I want to set a few fields as more important in the query than others.
As I understan, I can set it in the request using qf parameter.

Is it possible to define it in the schema so that its calculation will be done pre-query  thus faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either define [Index time boosts](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#index-time_boosts) for the individual documents and fields.
This might be a little faster but more difficult to debug the scores.

However, it would be better to have a request handler defined with the fields and their respective boosts.
Much more easy to customize and does not require re-indexing of the data as well.